# Removal operation in List<string>

Tags: c#, string

I have 2 Lists of type string:

- List1 has items - item1, item2, item3
- List2 has items - item2, item3

Now I need to compare both lists and remove the duplicated items from `List1`. The modified `List1` should have just one item, which is "item1".

foreach loops may work, but what I want to know is there any inbuilt method which does this?

### EDIT

Thanks for the answers guys. I was just thinking what would be the case if I wanted to add the missed out items into the List. So just raised another question similar to this.

[Add operation in List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797000/add-operation-in-liststring)

TIA!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect the best approach to use here would be to put the second list into a hash first, i.e.

```
var hash = new HashSet<TheType>(List2);
List1.RemoveAll(hash.Contains);
```

This avoids having O(n*m) performance, instead being O(n+m)

Example:

```
List<int> List1 = new List<int> {1,2,3};
List<int> List2 = new List<int> {2,3};

var hash = new HashSet<int>(List2);
List1.RemoveAll(hash.Contains);
// now List1 just has {1}
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use:

```
list1.RemoveAll(item => list2.Contains(item));
```

(As Marc says, this is O(N*M) - fine if you expect the lists to be very short, but awful if either of them could get big.)

Or if you don't mind it being a *new* list (rather than modifying the existing one), you could just use:

```
list1 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
List1 = List1.Except(List2).ToList();
```

Comment: That won't compile - Remove take a single item.

Comment: It still won't compile, as `Except` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Now it is *reassigning* `List1`, rather than mutating the original `List1`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: At which point your answer is the same as the second half as mine, but without the extra information :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using:

```
List1 = List1.Except(List2).ToList();
```