# Add operation in List<string>

Tags: c#, string, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge two object lists with linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720609/merge-two-object-lists-with-linq)

I have 2 `Lists` of type `string`:

```
List1 has items - item1, item2, item3

List2 has items - item1, item4, item5
```

Now I need to compare both `lists` and add the missing ones from `List2` into `List1`. The modified `List1` will be

```
list 1 : item1, item2, item3, item4, item5
```

Comment: var mergedList = list1.Union(list2).ToList();  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720609/merge-two-object-lists-with-linq

Answer (score 3):

you can use `LiNQ` for this:

```
List<string> newList = List1.Union(List2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this code - Except operator

```
var result = List2.Except(List1);

foreach(string item in result )
{
   List1.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use linq to do it

```
var result = List1.Union(List2);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   An IEnumerable that contains the elements from both input sequences, excluding duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

A simply way:

```
foreach(string item in List2)
{
if(!List1.Contains(item))
   List1.Add(item);
}
```

of course there are shorter (lenght of code) options

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LINQ` for this.

Look at the `Except` method and then join the resulting collection to you original collection.

See: http://csharp.net-tutorials.org/category/linq-to-objects/linq-except/